# How to make caption above minted listing?

Tags: captions, listings, minted

I am using `minted` package for my code:

```
\begin{listing}[htbp]
\begin{minted}[baselinestretch=1, 
                linenos, 
                xleftmargin=1.5em,
                breaklines]{solidity}
contract Delegate {
    address public owner;
    function pwn() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }  }
contract Delegation {
    address public owner;
    Delegate delegate;
    function() {
      if(delegate.delegatecall(msg.data)) {
        this;
    }  }  }
\end{minted}
\caption{The Triangle example}
\label{list:triangle}
\end{listing}
```

but the package always gives me like:

[image]

My question is how to make this code look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use the commands `\floatstyle`, `\newfloat` and `\floatname` of the package `float` (loaded by `minted`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{listing}{H}{lox}
\floatname{listing}{\strut Listing}

\begin{document}

\begin{listing}[htbp]
\begin{minted}[baselinestretch=1, 
                linenos, 
                xleftmargin=2em,
                breaklines]{solidity}
contract Delegate {
    address public owner;
    function pwn() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }  }
contract Delegation {
    address public owner;
    Delegate delegate;
    function() {
      if(delegate.delegatecall(msg.data)) {
        this;
    }  }  }
\end{minted}
\caption{The Triangle example}
\label{list:triangle}
\end{listing}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]